# Синтаксическая ошибка с союзом "и"

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, запятые, однородные-члены

**Можно работать в отделах, где вы будете сидеть за компьютером и заполнять таблицы в «1С», работать с документами, вести счета и заниматься другими важными задачами.**

Я знаю популярную синтаксическую конструкцию с однородными членами "O, O, O и O".
Не является ли синтаксической ошибкой использовать довольно странную конструкцию, как здесь: "O и О, О, О и О"?

Answer (score 1):

К грамматике особых вопросов нет, но эта грамматическая форма не подходит для семантики данного предложения. Дело в том, что **все перечисленные действия делаются с помощью компьютера, но это сложно выразить, используя союз И** и объединяя сказуемые в группы.

В качестве возможного варианта: **Можно работать в отделах, где вы будете сидеть за компьютером:  заполнять таблицы в «1С», работать с документами, вести счета и решать другие важные задачи.**

Для сравнения можно привести предложение **с той же группировкой сказуемых:**

Все дети были очень заняты. Они (1) сидели за столом и рисовАли, (2) играли в кУклы, (3) раскладывали кубики и строили из них дОмик.

Comment: М_Г прав, я имел в виду, что работа с документами, ведение счетов и другие важные дела связаны с "сидеть за компьютером". Как тогда поступить?

Comment: Я привела однозначный вариант, из которого ясно, что вся работа ведется за компьютером. Из вашего варианта можно понять, что на компьютере будут заполняться только таблицы. Работать же с документами и решать важные задачи можно по-разному, а неясность в этих вопросах очень нежелательна.

Comment: Понял. Подскажите, а если работа с документами, ведение счетов и другие важные дела НЕ были бы связаны с "сидеть за компьютером"? Как тогда лучше было бы оформить предложение?

Comment: Можно работать в отделах, где вы будете сидеть за компьютером и заполнять таблицы в «1С», или  заниматься с документами, вести счета и выполнять другие важные задачи.

Comment: Вы уверены, что союз "или" уместен, ведь здесь нет выбора или взаимоисключения? И почему перед ним запятую поставили?

Comment: Запятая закрывает придаточное. Союз ИЛИ может иметь значение чередования.

Comment: Так однородные члены после союза "или" как раз таки входят в придаточное.

Comment: Я по вашей просьбе предложила вариант, где работа за компьютером отделена от других работ, союз ИЛИ обозначает эту границу.

Comment: Про союз "или" я не спорю, я за запятую перед ней беспокоюсь. Получается, что "можно работать в отделах или заниматься с документами, вести счета и выполнять другие важные задачи". Или союз "или" вводит присоединительные члены?

Comment: Нет, это разделительный союз ИЛИ со значением чередования: вы можете выполнять разную работу (за компьютером и без него).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что между группами однородных членов, которые разделены союзом ИЛИ ставится запятая? О и О, или О, О и О. Просто я почему-то думал, что: О и О или О, О и О. Отсюда у меня и непонимание.

Comment: Союз ИЛИ может быть разделительным (запятая не ставится) или пояснительным (запятая ставится). В вашем предложении разделительный союз. Разделительный союз может выражать взаимоисключение (теперь или никогда) или замещение/чередование во времени. (идет дождь или снег). Ваше предложение неясно по смыслу, поэтому трудно подобрать грамматику. Всё происходит в отделе, везде стоят компьютеры, работа  с документами, счетами   тоже связана с компьютерами. Просто можно весь день сидеть за компьютером и заполнять таблицы, а можно только часть времени проводить за компьютером.

Comment: Вот и попробуйте всё это выразить так, чтобы было понятно, а уж потом расставляйте запятые. Мне кажется, что всё предложение надо перестраивать.

Comment: Если это разделительный союз и запятая не ставится, то в вашем варианте должно быть: "Можно работать в отделах, где вы будете сидеть за компьютером и заполнять таблицы в «1С» или заниматься с документами, вести счета и выполнять другие важные задачи". А вы запятую перед "или" почему-то поставили.

Answer (score 0):

Автор оставляет простор для понимания и толкования сказанного, а это —  недостаток. Текст должен быть составлен так, чтобы не вызывать вопросы о смысле сказанного.

Вот мне кажется, что заполнять таблицы придется сидя за компьютером, а  остальные виды работы (работа с документами, ведение счетов и другие важные дела) не будут связаны с сидением за компьютером. Расстановка запятых не противоречит и такому пониманию.

Дополнение:

> Я имел в виду, что работа с документами, ведение счетов и другие важные дела связаны с "сидеть за компьютером". Как тогда поступить?

Расстановкой союзов и запятых проблему не решишь.

Мой вариант:

Можно работать в отделах, где вы будете, **сидя за компьютером**, заполнять таблицы в «1С», работать с документами, вести счета и заниматься другими важными задачами.

Comment: Да, именно такой смысл и задумывался.

Comment: Текст должен быть составлен так, чтобы не вызывать вопросов  о смысле сказанного. Расстановкой союзов и запятых проблему не решишь.

Comment: Есть такое правило, что деепричастие или обстоятельство с целом всегда относится ко всем однородным членам?

Comment: Нет такого правила, здесь нужно руководствоваться тем, что называется common sense (здравый  смысл).